# Specify the active connection string to use in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

Is there a quick and easy way to set a connection string in Web.Config to be the active connection string?

I basically want to name my connection strings appropriately and then set one as active without having to switch out the names or re-compile my application.

Something like this:

```
<add name="Current" connectionString="{Local}"/>

<add name="Local" connectionString=[...]" />
<add name="RemoteOnMyServer" connectionString=[...]" />
<add name="RemoteAzure" connectionString=[...]" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible the way you asked. But you can move the connection strings block to a separate file and then control which FILE is the active one:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="LocalDb.config"/>
```

Then you can have separate config files:

```
LocalDb.config
RemoteOnMyServer.config
RemoteAzure.config
<etc>
```

Each one of there would hold something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="namedConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=..." providerName="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

Swithcing between them then becomes a matter of changing the `configSource` on the `<connectionStrings />` element.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has a good article describing using different configurations for different environments using the build setting in the compiler. I've used this with great success in some of my projects.

[Have a look](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx)