# Switching asp.net connection strings live/test/dev

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

We have a different set of connection strings in our config file as follows.

```
<!-- TEST CONNECTION STRING -->
<!--
<add name="fooConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Test_server;Initial Catalog=foo_dbTEST;User ID=foo_user;Password=abc1234;"/>
<add name="barConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Test_server;Initial Catalog=bar_dbTEST;User ID=bar_user;Password=abc1234;"/>
<add name="chewConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Test_server;Initial Catalog=chew_dbTEST;User ID=chew_user;Password=abc1234;"/>
-->

<!-- LIVE CONNECTION STRING -->

<add name="fooConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Live_server;Initial Catalog=foo_dbTest;User ID=fooTest_user;Password=abc1234;"/>
<add name="barConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Live_server;Initial Catalog=bar_Testdb;User ID=barTest_user;Password=abc1234;"/>
<add name="chewConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Live_server;Initial Catalog=chew_Test;User ID=chewTest_user;Password=abc1234;"/>

<!-- Local DEV CONNECTION STRING -->
<!--
<add name="fooConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyDoombaPC;Initial Catalog=fooDEVdbTest;User ID=foouser;Password=abc1234;"/>
<add name="barConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyDoombaPC;Initial Catalog=barDEVdb;User ID=barTestuser;Password=abc1234;"/>
<add name="chewConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyDoombaPC;Initial Catalog=chewDEVdb;User ID=chewuser;Password=abc1234;"/>
-->
```

When I need to change from, for example, live to test I move the XML comments from the Test section to the live section. Is there a more elegant way of doing this using Visual Studio 2010?

Just to be clear this is not a requirement of the application once it is in production, this is for developers to switch between different database connection string sets.

How do others approach this?

Comment: See a similar question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243215/specify-the-active-connection-string-to-use-in-web-config)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the web.config transformation : [web.config Transformation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx)

This will allow you to have seperate config files for both debug and release and have different setting in each.